# Access register api whitout jwt token

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony-4.3

I have this security.yml file

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:         "/secured/login_facebook"
                google:           "/secured/login_google"
            login_path:        fos_user_security_login
            failure_path:      fos_user_security_login
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: app.provider.oauth
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I have 2 sub-applications in my project : admin panel with login form + access after login and api. The problem is that the login works fine, but when I try to access /api/register I get the error :

> "JWT Token not found"

Have you an idea about that ? And is possible to have a list of api's that will be accessible in unauthentificated mode ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Although you have defined `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` for the path `^/api/register` under `access_control`, you need to setup a firewall that allows that path to be accessed anonymously.

The code below is an example on how to achieve that. Unfortunately I can't test it right now, so, you'll probably have to adjust it to your needs.

**Example 1:** Creating a new firewall:

```
firewalls:
//  ... the other firewalls you have
    register:
        pattern: ^/api/register
        anonymous: true
//      ... other configs you might need
```

**Example 2:** Adding the rules to an existing firewall entry:

```
firewalls:
//  ... the other firewalls you have
    login_register:
        pattern:  ^/api/
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path:               login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        register:
            check_path:               register
//          ... other configs you might need
```